# Is there a way to prevent automatic re-rendering when causing an event within a SectionList?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

This is my return function which contains all components in the renderer. Every time I press on the footerComponent in the Sectionlist, the whole screen re-renders and causes an auto-scroll to position 0.

```
return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <ImageBackground
        source={require("../assets/stars.gif")}
        style={{
          width: Dim.width,
          height: Dim.height,
        }}
        resizeMode="repeat"
      >
        {files ? <List /> : null}
        <CustomModal
          visible={visible}
          onPressIn={() => startRecording()}
          onPressOut={() => stopRecording()}
          onExitPress={() => setVisible(false)}
          onConfirm={() => sendToStorage(ID, len)}
          disabled={!strgUri}
          onDismiss={() => setRecording(null)}
          modalButton={[
            styles.modal,
            pressed
              ? { backgroundColor: Colors.clay }
              : { backgroundColor: Colors.aegean },
          ]}
          progress={progress}
          loadingVisible={sending}
        />
      </ImageBackground>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
```

and this is my Animated SectionList component.

```
const NewSectionList = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(SectionList);
  const List = React.forwardRef((ref, props) => {
    const respondRef = useRef();
    const scrollRef = useRef().current;

    function scrollToSection() {
      if (respondRef.current) {
        respondRef.current.measure((x, y, width, height, px, py) => {
          console.log("height: ", height);
          console.log("y: ", y);
          setHeight(py);
        });

        console.log("scrolling to: ", height);
        if (height != 0) {
          setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("wait height: ", height);
            console.log("dim height: ", Dim.height);

            console.log("1 height: ", Dim.height - height + Dim.height);

            scrollRef?.scrollTo({
              x: 0,
              y: Dim.height - height + Dim.height,
              animated: true,
            });
          }, 1000);
        }
      }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
      scrollToSection();
    });

    const yVal = fadeAnim.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 1],
      outputRange: [900, 0],
    });

    const animStyle = {
      transform: [
        {
          translateY: yVal,
        },
      ],
    };
return(
<Animated.View style={[animStyle]}>
        <NewSectionList
          ref={scrollRef}
          stickySectionHeadersEnabled={false}
          sections={files}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
          style={{
            marginLeft: 10,
            marginBottom: 110,
          }}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <View style={styles.cardContainer}>
              <View
                style={{
                  alignSelf: "flex-start",
                  position: "absolute",
                  marginTop: 5,
                }}
              >
                <Text p4 dusk>
                  {new Date(item.timestamp).toDateString()}
                </Text>
              </View>
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => visitProfile(item.name, item.email)}
              >
                <Text p2 aegean>
                  {item.name}
                </Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <View styles={styles.cardTap}>
                <TouchableNativeFeedback
                  onPress={() => {
                    playFile(item.url, item.id);
                  }}
                >
                  <AntDesign name="stepforward" size={40} color={Colors.led} />
                </TouchableNativeFeedback>
              </View>
            </View>
          )}
          renderSectionHeader={({
            section: {
              information,
              origin,
              userOrigin,
              emailOrigin,
              origID,
              originDate,
            },
          }) => (
            <View style={styles.headerContainer}>
              <View
                style={{
                  alignSelf: "flex-start",
                  position: "absolute",
                  marginTop: 5,
                }}
              >
                <Text p3 led>
                  {new Date(originDate).toDateString()}
                </Text>
              </View>
              <View style={styles.holder}>
                <TouchableOpacity
                  onPress={() => visitProfile(userOrigin, emailOrigin)}
                >
                  <Text h4 night>
                    {userOrigin}
                  </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
              <View style={styles.outerInfo}>
                <Text p3 dusk style={styles.textInfo}>
                  {information ? information : ""}
                </Text>
              </View>
              <View styles={styles.cardTap}>
                <TouchableNativeFeedback
                  onPress={() => {
                    playFile(origin, origID);
                  }}
                >
                  <AntDesign
                    name="stepforward"
                    size={40}
                    color={Colors.night}
                  />
                </TouchableNativeFeedback>
              </View>
            </View>
          )}
          renderSectionFooter={({ section: { docId, dataLen } }) => (
            <TouchableOpacity
              ref={respondRef}
              style={styles.notPressed}
              onPress={() => {
                setVisible(true);
                scrollToSection();
                setID(docId);
                setLen(dataLen);
              }}
            >
              <Text p2 white>
                add to convo
              </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          )}
          refreshControl={<RefreshControl onRefresh={() => getData()} />}
        />
      </Animated.View>
    );
  });
```

I tried to implement a scrollTo() method function to the position of the pressed button, but that is more of a hack than a real solution since it will keep re-rendering and scrolling. Also, the modal that I am trying to activate has other stateful components within it, causing more re-renders. Another attempted fix was trying to memo-ize the modal, however the official docs suggest that premature-optimization isn't not a real solution and will lead to more bugs down the . Thank you.

Comment: did u try providing some dependency to your useEffect hook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create new useEffect to debug whether `files` is always changed when your page is rerendered:

```
console.log('Screen in rerendered');
useEffect(() => {
   console.log('`files` is changed', JSON.stringify(files, undefined, 2));
}, [files]);
```

The files shouldn't be changed when you press footerComponent.

You may also want to wrap your `<Animated.View></Animated.View>` with `memo()` to prevent rerendering in its own component if the props are still equal.

Comment: I wrapped just the Animated.View in memo(), however this did not fix the issue, may I also ask what I am comparing props to in the memo() function? Also regarding the initial answer, the useEffect does not run on every time I press footerComponent.

Comment: The problem appears to be in the onPress section of the footer component. Whenever I set the modal to visible it changes state. Do you know a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the solution to my problem was actually just to render the CustomModal component within my List component so when i needed to show the modal, I could set state in the List component, rather than sending it to the parent. Sending it to the parent caused a re-render in the children component every time I would set the state to a different value. So in general if you want to prevent a re-render between siblings, just render the state dependent component in the one with state.